# How can I manage repositories that can only be synced via email

Tags: git, github

I have a situation where we are running a git-hub server on our intranet. My company workstation can check out a repo from this server no issues. BUT I must develop on a personal laptop that cannot be on the corporate network.

Currently, I have been ignoring the git repo, and just emailing myself the zipped up project. Split into 2 halves to squeeze under an email size limitation. Making the changes on my latop and then emailing myself back the changes via ZIP again.

There has got to be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is precisely what `git format-patch` is for.  If you started development on `master` for example, you can create a patch with `git format-patch origin/master` while you have `master` checked out.  This will create a series of patch files in the directory where you run the command.

You can email the patches to yourself (zipping them if you desire), or place them on a storage device.  Use `git apply` to apply these patch files to a clone on a machine attached to your corporate network.  This will recreate the commits you made on your laptop, and then you can push them as usual.

Comment: also `git bundle`, which was designed for exactly this purpose - incremental updates to a repo - and will be much more efficient than trying to import hundreds of patches, if your commit throughput is on the higher end...